# AccessDeniedException : An error occurred when calling the RegisterTaskDefinition operation

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I am registering one `JSON` file, with configuring `ecs`

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://task-definition.json --region us-west-2` It throws error

*Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"*

Then I perform `aws configure`& configure access, secret and region with default output format. like

```
AWS Access Key ID [****************WBCK]: 
AWS Secret Access Key [****************wrt1]: 
Default region name [us-west-2]: 
Default output format [None]: text
ubuntu@ip-172-31-27-83:~/SampleDocker$ aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://task-definition.json --region us-west-2

Still, I am occurring below error - 

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RegisterTaskDefinition operation: User: arn:aws:iam::581143930612:user/Nike is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
```

What are the missing roles? Any suggestions

Comment: I got it guys, i had not given permission to IAM user to access ecs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it guys, i had not given permission to IAM user to access ecs. 
IAM - User - Permission to

`AmazonECS_FullAccess` 
`AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`